# Run Drush command with Gulp

Tags: drush

I would to know how I can run a drush command like `drush @alias cc all` with a gulp workflow ?

This is my starting code:

```
var plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
    gulp.task('drush:cc', function () {

      return gulp.src(source)
        .pipe(plugins.shell([
          'drush @vmdevd6mg cc all'
        ])) 
        .pipe(plugins.notify({
          title: "Caches cleared",
          message: "Drush Drupal CSS/JS caches cleared.",
          onLast: true
        }));
    });
```

Thanks
EDIt: another way to run drush but seem not to work too,no error message given.

```
// Run drush to clear the theme registry.
gulp.task('drush', plugins.shell.task([
   'drush @vmdevd6mg cc all'
]));
```

both tasks give:

```
gulp drush 
Error: spawn drush @vmdevd6mg cc all ENOENT
```

EDIT1: New test

My new task and the result:

```
//Vidage de cache Drupal avec Drush
gulp.task('drush', function() {
  return gulp.src(basePaths.drushscript, {
      read: false
    })

    .pipe(plugins.shell([
      'drush @vmdevd6pf cron && drush @vmdevd6pf cc all'

    ]))
    .pipe(plugins.notify({
      title: "Vidage de Cache",
      message: "Cache Drupal vidé complètement.",
      onLast: true
    }));
});
```

Part of the global launch task:

gulp.watch(folderPaths.js.jsd68, ['drush']);

Give:

```
 /bin/sh: 1: drush: Permission denied

    events.js:160
          throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
    Error: Command `drush @vmdevd6pf cron && drush @vmdevd6pf cc all` failed with exit code 127
```

EDIT: final gulp task work like 
//Vidage de cache Drupal avec child_process - 2020-06

```
gulp.task('drush-cp', function(done) {
  return cp.spawn('drush', ['cache-rebuild'], {stdio: 'inherit'})
  .on('close', done)
   /*  .pipe(plugins.notify({
    title: "Vidage de Cache avec Drush",
    message: "Cache Drupal vidé complètement.",
    onLast: true
  })); */
  ;
});
```

Comment: Well, have you installed gulp shell plugin?

Comment: yes I did install it.

Comment: What is supposed to call this task?

Comment: This task is suppose to clear cache of a D6 site with using drush 8 and alias

Comment: No.,  what calls this task?

Comment: Don't know what to answer but I inspired me by this http://cgit.drupalcode.org/neato/tree/STARTER/gulpfile.js?id=a323cf1dcc88edb5639293467c0c860b8eae93cd#n72
Do you know about what drush is ?

Comment: Yes I wrote this. This is just the task definition. You still need a worker that calls it, typically gulp watch. Look at the watch task for an example there.

Comment: Yes I added the task to the watch task and I get ``[14:57:50] Starting 'drush:cc'...
[14:57:50] Finished 'drush:cc' after 12 μs
`` but I don't know if it really works

Comment: If you are running cc all, then your cache tables would be emptied out after it runs

Comment: yes it's the goal, but why gulp "say" nothing on what happen or not ? and how can I check if it does the job ?

Comment: It should, unless the notify plugin has changed. It puts a growl style message up for me on Mac OSX.

Comment: But how do you give the filepath to alias drush file ? Because I have two different task for drush.See EDIT original post.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The gulp shell plugin is basically piping commands to a shell and executing them. You can add dozens of drush tasks, just change the task name to whatever you want and change the implementation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58129/discussion-between-webmaster-pf-and-kevin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Try:

The first thing you’ll need is to import the dependency for “child process.” Next, you’ll want to set up an array variable containing all the paths to files you want auto-cache clearing setup for. This will basically be any Drupal template file. I would start with the main template directories you know you need it set up for and then add the additional paths along the way. Once we have our variables set, we then build our “clearcache” task using the “child_process” dependency that is shown below. Once we have all the pieces setup, we combine them in a watch task and let the magic happen! Using this task in your workflow will save you so much time, and even more importantly, save you the headache of clearing your cache every 2 minutes.

If you do run into some issues having your task running, make sure your Drush is setup and working in your command line as these Gulp task relies on Drush to complete its work.

## code:

```
var cp = require('child_process');
var drupal_files = "paths/to/your/drupal/files/you/want/auto-cache-clearing";
 
// Clearcache Task
gulp.task('clearcache', function(done) {
  return cp.spawn('drush', ['cache-rebuild'], {stdio: 'inherit'})
  .on('close', done);
});
 
gulp.watch(drupal_files, ['clearcache']);
```

Source: http://serversideguy.com/2018/02/05/how-can-i-automatically-clear-cache-for-drupal-using-gulp/